# How do I Execute Java from Java?

Tags: java, class, mouseevent

I have this `DownloadFile.java` and downloads the file as it should:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.URL;

public class DownloadFile {    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String fileName = "setup.exe";
            // The file that will be saved on your computer
        URL link = new URL("http://onlinebackup.elgiganten.se/software/elgiganten/setup.exe");
            // The file that you want to download

        // Code to download
        InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(link.openStream());
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        int n = 0;
        while (-1 != (n = in.read(buf))) {
            out.write(buf, 0, n);
        }
        out.close();
        in.close();
        byte[] response = out.toByteArray();

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
        fos.write(response);
        fos.close();
        // End download code

        System.out.println("Finished");
    }
}
```

I want to execute this from a mouse event in `Gui.java`.

```
private void jLabel17MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt){

}
```

How do I do this?

Comment: How do we run static methods from other classes?

Answer (score 2):

Your current method is a static method, which is fine, but all the data that it extracts is held tightly within the main method, preventing other classes from using it, but fortunately this can be corrected.

My suggestion:

- re-write your DownloadFile code so that it is does not simply a static main method, but rather a method that can be called by other classes easily, and that returns the data from the file of interest. This way outside classes can call the method and then receive the data that the method extracted.
- Give it a String parameter that will allow the calling code to pass in the URL address.
- Give it a File parameter for the file that it should write data to.
- Consider having it return data (a byte array?), if this data will be needed by the calling program.
- Or if it does not need to return data, perhaps it could return boolean to indicate if the download was successful or not.
- Make sure that your method throws all exceptions (such as IO and URL excptions) that it needs to throw.
- Also, if this is to be called by a Swing GUI, be sure to call this type of code in a background thread, such as in a SwingWorker, so that this code does not tie up the Swing event thread, rendering your GUI frozen for a time.

Comment: thx, a lot of "good" info, but iam a level zero java coder =) The Downloadfile.java i got from the internet =)

Comment: @TorbjörnDahlgren: then this is a perfect chance for you to play with that code and to try to get it to work for your purposes. This is how you learn, and for many of us, how the fun begins. Then later if your code has problems, post them here in a new question. Note that as a general rule, you'll want to avoid borrowing code from online, but rather borrow *ideas*, and use them to write your own code, as this will improve your understanding of the ideas and code. Good luck!

Comment: You are right, but so i know how do i call a method from another.java file?

Comment: @TorbjörnDahlgren: [here are the Java tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reallybigindex.html), search it on the term `method` and have a look through. Please note though that the questions you are asking are usually found in information that you learn *before* trying to do more complex coding such as downloading files or creating GUI's. Since you're just learning Java, consider going through all the introductory sections of the tutorial that I linked to above and/or go through a decent Java textbook. You won't regret doing this.